# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 in Xcode 8.1, Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, segmentation-fault, swift3, xcode8

I know this question was asked before, but other questions relate to the older Xcode versions and answers suggest that this bug was resolved.

I get this error on the newest `Xcode 8.1 (8B62)` which is the most recent one (and `Swift3`) and still can not find a solution for my case.

**Happens when:**

- `Swift 3` and `Objective-C` are bridged together.
- `Swift` code calls `Objective-C` method which may throw an error (not in all but in specific cases only, more details in included code snippets below).

I was struggling with this for almost whole day and dissected the essence into the minimum demonstration project capable of reproducing this mysterious error. 
It is available for everyone on `GitHub`, so feel free to try and help with this:

**UPDATE - Includes solution and explanation to the issue:** (thanks to *@CodaFi*)
https://github.com/lukaszmargielewski/SegmentationFault11

Here is the code causing it:

**Swift 3 code:**

```
   class SegmentationFault11 {

        let responseProcessor = NetworkResponseProcessor() // Objective-C class
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!

        func epicFail() {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    _ = try self.responseProcessor.process(response, data: data, networkError: error)
                } catch {}
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

**Objective-C code:**

```
// NetworkResponseProcessor.h

@interface NetworkResponseProcessor : NSObject

- (nullable id)process:(nullable NSURLResponse *)response
                  data:(nullable NSData *)data
          networkError:(nullable NSError *)networkError
                 error:(NSError * _Nonnull * _Nullable)error;

@end
```

Comment: You have your `NSError` nullability qualifiers wrong in all but one of the method declarations.  The innermost pointer is, in fact, required to be nullable if you want proper writeback semantics.  The Swift compiler assumes you know this and crashes instead of emitting a diagnostic (bug!).  Please file a bug report on bugs.swift.org if you haven't already and try to do so as well in the future.  It's hard to find compiler bugs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Filed a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3272